# Events don't get hit WCF Service implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, event-handling, servicecontract

I have a WCF Service interface, a class that implements the contract and a hosting winforms application. This then starts worker processes who connect back to the WCF server and then the events should be getting triggered. The client worker process is not having any issues making the calls to the methods and followed by that I am expecting the attached event handlers be called within the Windows forms application too but this is not happening:

```
                    xWCFService xWCFService = new xWCFService();
                    xWCFService.eventWorkerProcessStart += new EventHandler<WorkerProcessProgressChangedEventArgs>(xWCFService_eventWorkerProcessStart);
                    xWCFService.eventWorkerProcessStop += new EventHandler<WorkerProcessProgressChangedEventArgs>(xWCFService_eventWorkerProcessStop);
                    xWCFService.eventWorkerProcessUpdateProgress += new EventHandler<WorkerProcessProgressChangedEventArgs>(xWCFService_eventWorkerProcessUpdateProgress);
                    xWCFService.eventWorkerProcessError += new EventHandler<WorkerProcessProgressChangedEventArgs>(xWCFService_eventWorkerProcessError);


                    ServiceHost xServiceHost = new ServiceHost(xWCFService, new Uri(serviceAddress));

                    xServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IxWCFServiceContract), new NetTcpBinding(), address);
                    xServiceHost.Open();
```

I am passing the instance of the Service class to the servicehost and it is a singleton instance. I appreciate any help/insight that can be provided on why I'm not referencing the correct instance.

Answer (score 0):

After much reading I have noticed my mistake in the client side code:

```
            static xWCFService xwcfService = new xWCFService();

           ....
       {
            EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(string.Format(xWCFServerBaseAddress, address) + address));
            Binding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            xChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IxWCFServiceChannel>(binding, endPoint);
            xChannelFactory.Open();
            xServiceChannel = xChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            xServiceChannel.Open();

            **xwcfService.WorkerProcessStartedParsing(strGuidClientIdentifier);**
```

This last line was my mistake, I was invoking the calls on the service through an instance of the service implementation class. When I used the xServiceChannel to invoke the methods on the service, all events were raised.